# foreman start error, Procfile does not exist

Tags: python, django, vagrant, foreman

**Directory Contents**

```
sid@midnight:~/kuma$ ls
admin_dashboard.py                   requirements
celery.py                            scripts
configs                              settings_local.py
contribute.json                      settings.py
CONTRIBUTING.md                      settings_test.py
docs                                 settings_travis.py
etc                                  templates
kuma                                 tests
kumascript                           tox.ini
kumascript_settings_local.json       urls.py
kumascript_settings_local.json-dist  vagrantconfig_local.yaml
LICENSE                              vagrantconfig_local.yaml-dist
manage.py                            vagrantconfig.yaml
media                                Vagrantfile
migrations                           vendor
Procfile                             webroot
puppet                               wsgi
README.rst
```

Then I did `vagrant ssh`
Which succeeded with `Last Login:...`

Then I did `foreman start`, which gave

```
vagrant@developer-local:~$ foreman start
ERROR: Procfile does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong?? I'm a beginner to this stuff, please go easy on me. Thank you.

Comment: Does `foreman start -f /vagrant/Procfile` work?

Comment: what is (after you `vagrant ssh`) the output of `ls -la /vagrant`?

Comment: You've ssh-ed to your vagrant box, but you don't seem to have gone into a direcory which contains your code. Remember vagrant has its own file system.

Comment: @dusan.bajic
`vagrant@developer-local:~$ ls -la /vagrant`
`ls: cannot access /vagrant: No such file or directory`

Comment: @DanielRoseman: kuma is the folder where my code is. Before doing `vagrant  up` , I went into kuma. Or do I have to go into some other folder after I do `vagrant ssh` ??

Comment: The directory you enter beforehand is irrelevant. You're SSH-ing into what is effectively a completely separate machine. You need to make your code available on that machine somehow - either by installing it separately or by sharing a directory with the host machine - and then go to the place where the code is. If you did `ls` on the guest machine it would be obvious that your code isn't there.

Comment: So, what exact steps should I take now?
Clone the code from git after ssh?